# listbox control ownerdraw question( adding a edit control to the listbox item )

Tags: c#, controls, ownerdrawn

I am using owner draw variable style for a listbox( winforms 2.0)
when a user selects an items I want to draw an edit control in that cell
Is that doable
not a drop down but an actual edit control appearing in the cell or item as it were
how
thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want an editable dropdown list? Where the user can choose from the items in the list, or enter their own value in a textbox?

Comment: Are you working on a desktop application (WinForms) or a web app (ASP.Net)? There is a huge difference when you are trying to do this. By the way, it is perfectly acceptable for you to edit your question to clarify these issues.

Comment: And if desktop, you'll want to be sure to clarify winforms vs wpf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using some similar for ListView. Method is:

1. Create TextBox, add to Controls array, and hide one.

   innerTextBox.Size = new Size(0, 0);

   innerTextBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);

   this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { this.innerTextBox });

   innerTextBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.EditOver);

   innerTextBox.LostFocus += new EventHandler(this.FocusOver);

   innerTextBox.Hide();

   innerTextBox.Text = "";
2. On DoubleClick event bind own method where find selected Item and get value to TextBox

   this.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(this.EditableDoubleClick);

   private void EditableDoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {

   selectedItemText = selectedItem.ToString();

   innerTextBox.Size = new Size(subItemRect.right - subItemRect.left, subItemRect.bottom - subItemRect.top);

   innerTextBox.Location = new Point(subItemRect.left, subItemRect.top);

   innerTextBox.Show();

   innerTextBox.Text = selectedItemText;

   }
3. On lost focus in TextBox - set value back into selected item.

   selectedItem = innerTextBox.Text;